# Can .addField value write an array that contains file "names"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I'm currently making a discord bot, and I made a ~play command that reads files from a folder (songs) and stores them in an array, then it picks a random file and plays it in the voice channel.

Right now I want to make a ~songs that makes the bot send an embed in the chat that contains `.setTitle("These are that I have:")`, and then `.addField({name: "songs:", value: "*all the songs in the array"})`.

The reason I want all songs in one Field value is that there are too many songs, and there are only 25 field that I can use. I tried `forEach` in the value and outside the field but none of them worked well.

Here's my code:

```
const discord = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  const songFiles = fs
    .readdirSync("./commands/Workout/")
    .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".mp3"));

  let songsEmbed = new discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("RANDOM")
    .setTitle("These are that I have:");

  //.addField('Songname:',commandFiles.forEach())//doesn't work

  for (i = 0; i < commandFiles.length; i++) {
    songsEmbed.addField({ name: "Song name:", value: `${commandFiles[i]},` });
  } //That just create field for every song

  message.reply(songsEmbed);
};

module.exports.help = {
  name: "songs",
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `.join()` function to create a string with the entries.

Let's say we have this array:

```
const songArray = [
  "Toto - Africa.mp3",
  "Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up.mp3"
  "Bag Raiders - Shooting Stars.mp3"
]
```

We can then run `.join()` to create a string with each song in that array. Note that `\n` indicates a new line.

```js
songArray.join('\n')

/*
Toto - Africa.mp3
Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up.mp3
Bag Raiders - Shooting Stars.mp3
*/
```

So your code would look like this:

```js
.addField('Songname:', commandFiles.join('\n'))
```